# How to correctly bind (update) a DataGrid with a CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection, collectionviewsource

I have a (WPF) DataGrid where I attach an ICollectionView as

**XAML:**

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="TodoList" ItemsSource="{Binding TodoItemsCollection}" DataContext="{Binding}" />
```

**Constructor (Code behind)**

```
 TodoItemsCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Storage.TodoItems);
 TodoItemsCollection.Filter = TodoItemsFilter;
```

(Storage.TodoItems is an ObservableCollection)

**TodoItemsCollection Property**

```
 private ICollectionView _todoItemsCollection;
 public ICollectionView TodoItemsCollection
 {
     get { return _todoItemsCollection; }
     set 
     {
         if (_todoItemsCollection != value)
         {
             _todoItemsCollection = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("TodoItemsCollection");
         }
     }
 }
```

Storage.TodoItems is an **ObservableCollection where a tracker adds, edits and removes items**.
This changes should immediately be displayed in the DataGrid.

However, the problem is that all those **changes are not reflected in the DataGrid** (i.e. the DataGrid is not updated).
For example if I call `TodoItemsCollection.Refresh()`, nothing changes.
With a refresh button (only for testing purposes), I set the ItemsSource of the DataGrid to null and reset it (`TodoItemsCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Storage.TodoItems);`).
This manual refresh displays the new/changed/removed items.
However, the **filtering then doesn't work anymore**.

I read about three dozens of blog posts and couldn't find a solution to my problems.
Usually, calling `Refresh()` or resetting the `ItemsSource` worked well for them.

Any **suggestions** are really much appreciated!!

Comment: Avoid setting the bound collection to null, instead use Clear(). As for your issues, you could try OnPropertyChanged(() => TodoItemsCollection);

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know what you mean. I set the TodoList.ItemsSource to null. And I cannot call `Clear()` on TodoItemsCollection. What should I do? Thank you!

Comment: I can't use a LambdaFunction inside OnPropertyChanged(). How do you suggest that the OnPropertyChanged()-Method should look like? Thanks.

Comment: For me the solution was to reassign `ItemsSource` in the code behind. `TodoList.ItemsSource = TodoItemsCollection;`

Answer (score 3):

in addition to liquidsnake786 answer - you can use the ObservableCollection instead of the ICollectionView and filtering/sorting will work just the same as long as you use CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Storage.TodoItems).

the more important thing is that the Storage.TodoItems should just initialize once otherwise TodoItemsCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Storage.TodoItems); have to be called every time a new Storage.TodoItems is created. simply use clear() add() and remove() to alter your Storage.TodoItems.

EDIT: the usual way:

-just create a OberservableCollection once (eg. within ctor). this collection will handle Add and Remove and notify the WPF ui.

```
this.MyCollection = new OberservableCollection<TodoItem>();
```

-your wrapped item "TodoItem" should implement INotifyPropertyChanged to notifiy changes/edits to WPF ui

-create you ICollectionView once(eg. within the ctor) like you did

```
 this.MyView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyCollection);
 this.MyView.Filter = TodoItemsFilter;
```

-alter your source collection with clear, add, remove

```
 this.MyCollection.Clear();
 foreach(var item in MyNewCollectionFromAnywhere)
 { this.MyCollection.Add(item);}
 this.MyView.Refresh();
```

-be sure that your datacontext and binding is right in xaml :) btw DataContext="{Binding}" makes no sense for me.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyView}"/>
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Am I not already doing this by writing `TodoItemsCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Storage.TodoItems);`? TodoItems is an ObservableCollection where the items are added/modified/removed. But I can't run clear() on this list, as I don't want to alter it. Basically, the DataGrid should just show the whole ObservableCollection, but enable the user to filter it (with separate fields). Could you please show me how I could change my code to make it work? Thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately not. But it did help me insofar as I could improve my understanding of the CollectionViewSources-Stuff. Moreover, the filter now still works after a user manually refreshes. However, I really hope to find a solution to not have to rely on the refresh button. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using ObservableCollection instead of ICollectionView and see if it helps. You should be able to call Clear() on that collection as well

[image: Sorting]

Comment: Just binding an ObservableCollection to the DataGrid works. But I want to run fiters on it and that's why I am using ICollectionView. Or do I misunderstand your answer? Thanks.

Comment: See this diagram, maybe it will help you understand what i am ttrying to say... http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/luc/WindowsLiveWriter/SortsandfiltersonObservableCollection_D09D/image4_thumb.png